# GreenDroid Paged View - Detect if last page

Tags: android, greendroid

I made a class `MyPagedView` extends `GDActivity` and have a `PagedView`.

I implemented a working `PagedAdapter` as class `MyPagedAdapter`.

> I would like to be able to get out of the PagedView once the latest page have been displayed to make a tutorial/introduction to my Android application.

Please help me I can't find the right method to get triggered once the slides have reach the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html).. the `onPageSelected(int position)` is most likely the callback that you need.

```
void onPageChanged(int position) {
    if (position == pageCount-1) {
       /* you are on last page */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked with `OnPagedViewChangeListener` and `onPageChanged(PagedView pagedView, int previousPage, int newPage)` with `if (newPage == PAGE_COUNT - 1)`